# Test Automation TestLink/Jenkins/Selenium: Maven issue

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, testng

I run test cases from jenkins with testng and i export the results in test link thanks to TestLink Plugin.

I have a little problem, since yesterday i try to get the test cases using git. I can download all the git repo, but when i build the project in jenkins, maven try to compile all the files downloaded from git repo (about 4500 files) and i have only 5 test cases at the moment ...

my Git repo looks like

```
Folder 1 -> ...
Folder 2 -> ...
FolderTest->src->MyTestCasesAreHere.java
```

Is there any way to specify the path of the test cases, or to make maven compile only the files i want ?

i "invoke top level maven targets" with maven targets :`test -DsuiteXmlFiles=suite.xml`
is it the right way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to build a subproject change the Root POM option under the Build section of your Jenkins job configuration.  This is assuming that you are using the Maven2/3 job type.

Also, if that doesn't work think about passing in the -f command line option to Maven to control which POM your build is going to use: http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html